# StreamedResponse not working

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have a lengthy import process and I am trying to use the new [StreamedResponse](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#streaming-a-response) available in Symfony 2.1 to report some feedback about the task to the user but the response is not being streamed (I get all the content at once at the end of processing). This is my code in my controller:

```
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $response = new StreamedResponse();
            $response->setCallback(function () use ($em) {
                $file = fopen(sys_get_temp_dir().'/categories.txt', 'r');
                $lineNum = 0;
                while ($line = fgets ($file)) {
                    $category = new Category();
                    $fields = explode("\t",$line);
                    $category->setFullId($fields[0]);
                    $category->setName($fields[2]);
                    $category->setFullName($fields[4]);
                    $em->persist($category);
                    if ($lineNum%100==0) {
                        echo 'Processing Line: '.$lineNum.'<br>';
                        flush();                            
                        $em->flush();
                    }
                    $lineNum++;
                }
                fclose($file);
            });
            return $response;
```

Any idea what may be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I found it: you need to call both `ob_flush()` and `flush()`.

Comment: Awesome! What's the reason for this? I never heard of ob_flush before. Well done!

Comment: The ob_ range of functions set up an internal buffer so that any output made by the code is output to this buffer. This is used for example by the Response to catch all output from templating, etc... and then redirect it back to the browser. This is why you need to call it in this situation

Comment: @CarlosGranados but Response doesn't use ob_start function ;) I think you just have output_buffering enabled by php configuration.

Comment: Yes, I have output_buffering enabled but this has nothing to do with ob_ buffers

Comment: Yes it does, turning output buffering on is the same as calling ob_start at the top of your code.

Comment: I didn´t know that!! I thought they were different buffers! Thanks for this